# Find value of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{10}{(-1)^k C(10,k)/(2^k)}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

> Find value of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{10}{(-1)^k\dbinom{10}{k}\dfrac{1}{2^k}}$

Do I have to open the factorials of all combinations, or is there any other way? please help.

Comment: No, you should realise this is a special case of a famous theorem.

Comment: Please tell me the  name of theorem

Comment: You are dealing with **binomial** coefficients and you want a **theorem**. What can you possibly come up with?

Comment: So, please tell me how can I do this question

Comment: Oh I finally got answer

Answer (score 0):

You have $$(x-1)^{10} = \sum_{k=1}^{10}C(10,k)x^k(-1)^{10-k}$$.

Note that $(-1)^{10-k} = (-1)^k$, for all $0 \leq k \leq 10$.

Taking $x=\frac{1}{2}$, you have a result.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
$$\sum_{k=0}^{10}\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^k\cdot \binom{10}{k}\cdot1=\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{10}$$